# Can a class template be a function

Tags: c++

I have a function

```
double function(const infocontainer&);
```

It's passed to another function as a parameter.

```
void bigfunction(std::ostream& os, const std::string& s, double F(const infocontainer&), const infocontainer a, const infocontainer b)
{
    os << F(a) << F(b) << std::endl;
}
```

When I used templates though I need to give F the address of infocontainer a and b. Why?

```
template <class F> void bigfunction(std::ostream& os, const std::string& s, F, const infocontainer a, const infocontainer b)
{
    os << F(&a) << F(&b) << std::endl;
}
```

This is how I call the function in `MAIN`

```
bigfunction(std::cout, "name", function, cont_a, cont_b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your template definition `F` is a *type name*, not a function pointer. So, the `F(x)` notation will be interpreted by the compiler as an attempt to *cast* `x` to type `F`. It is not a function call, it is a C++-style cast. This is completely different from what you are trying to do. And this is why you "have" to use `&a` and `&b` as arguments, since compiler wants *pointer* arguments for the cast to function pointer type `F`. All this, of course, makes no sense whatsoever.

What you have to do is name your function parameter

```
template <class F> void bigfunction(std::ostream& os, const std::string& s, F f, 
                                    const infocontainer a, const infocontainer b)
```

(Why did you omit the name the first place?)

And then call the function without any `&`

```
os << f(a) << f(b) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to distinguish the (deduced) type from the name of the parameter:

```
template <class F>
void bigfunction(std::ostream& os, const std::string& s, F& f, const infocontainer a, const infocontainer b)
{
    os << f(&a) << f(&b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, since you corrected the issue with parameter name, you no longer have to use `&` when calling `f`.